# Nuxtで作ったサイトが表示されない

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

`asyncData` からのデータを `head` で使っています。
ローカル環境では表示されますが、本番環境になるとAPIの読み込みがされず、ブラウザにAPIの情報が表示されません。

APIの呼び出しをmounted内に書いたら表示はされましたが、代わりにOGPが表示されなくなりました...
拙い説明ですいません。どうかよろしくお願いします。

---

**エラーメッセージ**

````
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined```
````

**該当のソースコード**

```
<div class="contents-header">  
  <h1>{{posts.title}}</h1>  
</div>  

export default {  
  data(){
    return {
    }
  }, 
  head(){
    return{
      title: this.posts.title,
      meta:[
        { hid: 'title', name: 'title', content: this.posts.title }
      ]
    }
  },
  async asyncData({app,params,error}) {  
    const {id} = params;  
    const response = await axios.get(`https://hogehoge.com/api/v1/posts/${id}`)  
      .catch(err=> {
        error({  
          statusCode: err.response.status,  
          message: err.response.data.message,  
        });  
        return err.response;  
      });  
    const posts = JSON.parse(response.data)  
    return {posts};  
  }
}
```

Comment: 申し訳ございませんでした。もう一度編集いたしました。動作も確認済みです。

Comment: 回答される方へ https://teratail.com/questions/238505

Comment: apiのレスポンスを共有していただけますか？

Comment: api のレスポンスが間違っているときに何が起こるかも考慮していませんでした。